# NoSQL redeployable database?

Tags: database, nosql

Is there any lightweight version of nosql database system which can be easily redeployed - like MSSQL compact / SQLite?

Like db engine binaries need to be only copied - actual data is stored in a file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`RavenDB`](http://ravendb.net/) which can work in an [`embedded mode`](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded).

Quote from the documentation:

> RavenDB makes it very easy to be embedded within your application. The
>   first step is to reference the embedded client, either via nuget
>   (package name: RavenDB-Embedded) or by taking the files from the build
>   zip.
>
> After referencing the embedded client from your project, all that is
>   left to do is initializing:
>
> `var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory = "Data" };`

Comment: Thanks Darin it is something useful.